# Chrome doesn't recognize that I already have Java installed

Tags: java, jdk, jre

I've installed the latest JDK which also installs the JRE (1.8.0.25) The paths all seem to be set fine and Eclipse runs just fine.

But my browsers do not recognize that Java is installed and want me to download the JRE again. How to I get chrome (and others) to see see that I already have java installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install the 32 bit or 64 bit version of Java? Most likely you have the 32 bit version of chrome, so you'll need 32 bit Java for it to be compatible with Chrome.

Comment: Ah, I did install the 64 bit version of the jdk/jde

Comment: ok, installed the 64 bit version of Chrome, and it runs my version of java just fine. Thanks. (upvoted and accepted)

Comment: Glad it's working fine now~